# Python create a matrix of rolling 1s along the diagonal

Tags: python, matrix

I want to create a matrix with n columns of k 1s in each row rolling from left to right. (n-k elements in each row are 0)
example:

k = 4, n = 10

result:

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0  
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0  
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0  
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0  
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0  
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

how can I create this matrix fast and smart?

Comment: Please post your attemnpted solution

Answer (score 2):

The best answer depends what you mean by "smart".  A memory-efficient approach is to stride a 1-d array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
>>> a = np.zeros(2*n-k, dtype=int)
>>> a[n-k:n] = 1
>>> view = as_strided(a[n-k:], shape=(n-k+1, n), strides=(-8, 8))
>>> view.tolist()
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

This view uses 16 integers of storage for a 70 integer array.

An alternate approach is to observe that the ravelled array has a repeating pattern of 4 ones followed by 7 zeros.  So you could tile that and reshape:

```
>>> r = n-k+1
>>> np.tile([1]*k+[0]*r, r)[:-r].reshape(r,n)
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

If you don't want to use numpy, and were just looking for a straight-forward and Pythonic approach, you could roll a `deque` and accumulate:

```
from collections import deque

data = [1]*k + [0]*(n-k)
d = deque(data)
result = [data]
while not d[-1]:
    d.rotate(1)
    result.append(list(d))
```

A listcomp of listcomps is possible (this one is not mine, found in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43844714#43844714)):

```
>>> [[1 if 0<=i-j<k else 0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n-k+1)]
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
[list(map(int, list(bin(2**10 + (2**4 - 1) * 2**expo)[3:]))) for expo in range(6, -1, -1)]
```

output:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```